# Delete sections of a file based on some string search in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two files with following contents

File1
dn: cn=Abcd
objectClass:
objectClass: top
cn: Abcd

File 2
dn: cn=Abcd
objectClass:
objectClass: top
AdminDevType:
ConfigID: Abcd
EventID: Abcd
cn: Abcd
parent:
Template: Something.cfgtpl

dn: cn=Peter
objectClass:
objectClass:
AdminDevType:
IOSConfigID: Peter
IOSEventID: Peter
cn: Peter
parent:
Template: Something.cfgtpl

dn: cn=mohan
objectClass:
objectClass:
IOSconfigtemplate:
AdminDevType:
IOSConfigID: mohan
IOSEventID: mohan
cn: mohan
parent:

Now the task is I have to search file1 for pattern cn= or cn: throught out the file1 and store all the values in some array or something else.....like here we will get only one value i.e. Abcd
After this is done now I have to search for all the strings found in file1 in file2 and if it is found then delete whole section staring from dn: cn=Abcd till the next occurrence of pattern dn:
Similarly we need to search for all values that file1 returns and delete the required section if there is a match through out the file2.

Please suggest how to do this in shell script. Thanks In Advance

Comment: would be helpful to show File2 where there is some stuff to delete and some stuff to keep.

Comment: But there isn't a `Template` in file1 so how will we know where to delete until?

Comment: If the process is completely symmetrical, surely you can reverse the order of the input files and just run it again, can't you?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]=]+' '
    # extract the CNs from file1
    NR == FNR {
        if (/^cn:/ || /^dn: cn=/) 
            cn[$NF] = 1
        next
    }

    # process file2, removing sections where CN was in file1
    /dn:/ {deleteThis = ($NF in cn)}
    !deleteThis;
    /^Template:/ {deleteThis = 0}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi , I have modified contents in file2 which needs not to be deleted. Only value matching from file1 should be deleted. And also it should delete the section till next occurence of dn:

Comment: Yes, and? Did you even try my solution?